# NumLock breaks Alt_L key

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

When I enable NumLock through my keyboard, all Alt_L shortcuts (e.g. Alt_L + Arrow_L in Firefox) aren't executed at all.

When using xev, it shows me that Alt_L cause focus loss when NumLock is active.

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x13e, subw 0x0, time 3586896, (1116,872), root:(1253,1037),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x13e, subw 0x0, time 3587010, (1116,872), root:(1253,1037),
    state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x13e, subw 0x0, time 3589052, (1116,872), root:(1253,1037),
    state 0x0, keycode 77 (keysym 0xff7f, Num_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x13e, subw 0x0, time 3589157, (1116,872), root:(1253,1037),
    state 0x10, keycode 77 (keysym 0xff7f, Num_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  96  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear
```

Specs:

```
OS: Ubuntu 17.10 x86_64
Host: 20FH002RGE ThinkPad T560
Kernel: 4.13.0-16-generic
Resolution: 2880x1620
DE: ubuntu:GNOME
WM: GNOME Shell
WM Theme: Adwaita
Terminal: gnome-terminal
Keyboard layout: German
```

---

Is there any way to change this behaviour so I can use NumLock and Alt_L together?